# Реализация полиморфизма при выборы структуры очереди

Tags: c++, qt, полиморфизм

Пытаюсь реализовать очередь при помощи списка и массива.
В начале программы я выбираю реализацию  очереди и дальше работа программы ведется с этой реализацией.
Хочу сделать так, чтобы был единый интерфейс.
То есть чтобы у меня были бы перегруженные функции, например

```
int Size(Queue1 *Q) //размер очереди МАССИВ
{
    return Q->last;
}
int Size(Queue *Q) //размер очереди
{
     return Q->size;
}
```

В начале программы я осуществляю выбор и вот так хочу объявить `Q`.

```
bool real=kindstack(); //true-list , false-array
if (real) //выбираю между списком и массивом
{
    Queue Q; //список
    Creation(&Q); //создаем список
    Add(&Q,secType);
}
else
{
    Queue1 Q;
    Creation(&Q);
}
```

Однако, на этапе компиляции я столкнулся с вот такой ошибкой:

> "Q" was not declareted in this Scope.

на строчке:

```
if  (Size(&Q)==1)
 ...
```

Что я делаю не так?

Comment: а это нормально что такой строчки в выше представленном код нет?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Есть много различных путей, но обычно то, чего вы ходите, достигается при помощи динамического полиморфизма.

Объявляем общий интерфейс:

```
class AbstractQueue // интерфейс
{
public:
    virtual size_t GetSize() = 0;
    virtual void Enqueue(int value) = 0;
};
```

Конкретная имплементация с использованием `std::vector`:

```
class ArrayQueue : public AbstractQueue
{
    vector<int> payload;
public:
    virtual size_t GetSize() { return payload.size(); };
    virtual void Enqueue(int value)  { payload.push_back(value); };
};
```

Конкретная имплементация с использованием ручной реализации связного списка:

```
class LinkedListQueue : public AbstractQueue
{
    class Node { public: Node* next; int value };
    Node* head;
    Node* tail;
    size_t count;
public:
    LinkedListQueue() : head(nullptr), tail(nullptr), count(0) {}
    virtual size_t GetSize() { return count; };
    virtual void Enqueue(int value)
    {
        Node* node = new Node();
        node->value = value;
        node=>next = nullptr;
        if (tail)
            tail->next = node;
        else
            head = node;
        tail = node;
        count++;
    };
};
```

Теперь вы можете обращаться с структурой данных абстрактным образом, отвлекаясь от того, какая это конкретно структура данных.

```
AbstractQueue* q = kindstack(); // возвращает тот или иной класс очереди
q->Enqueue(1);
size_t c = q->GetSize();
```

Answer (score 0):

Компилятор Вам, собственно прямо говорит о том что ему не нравится. Во втором блоке кода Вы объявляете переменную Q внутри блока if, и после выхода из блока она уже не видна.
Нужно переписать функцию Qreation, чтобы она возвращала указатель на класс, базовый для Queue и Queue1:

```
BaseQueue *q = creation();
```

а потом лучше сделать так (для получения размера):

```
int s = q->size();
```

Функция size() должна быть виртуальной в BaseQueue и реализована в Queue и Queue1.